# Multiple varying xhr requests so responses are no more than 1 minute apart?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have an xhr request that I need to poll, which can take anywhere from 1 minute to 3 minutes to send back a response. Ideally I would like to receive a response no more than 1 minute from the previous response. What would be the best approach to try to achieve this?

My naive approach is:

```
function xhr(){
  //... send xhr and process response
}


[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((item, index) ->
  setTimeout(() => {
    xhr()
    setInterval(() => xhr(), 4 * 60 * 1000)
  }, index * 60 * 1000)

)
```

But that kind of assumes they will all take 3 minutes. Is there a better way?

Edit: to clarify, I'm hoping to do it so that there are multiple xhr requests going in parallel so that they overlap hopefully so that at any point there is no more than a 1 minute gap between the responses.

Comment: If the response is three minutes how could client adjust the response?

Comment: I'm typing from a mobile so cannot provide an example but in the success/response of a xhr request you could do a call back or call function which provides the next xhr request

Comment: @guest271314 The response is anywhere from 1 minute to 3 minutes. I'm hoping to do it so that there are multiple xhr requests going in parallel so that they overlap hopefully so that at any point there is no more than a 1 minute gap between the responses.

I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: If you cannot control the response time what is the issue with code at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I was wondering if there was a better approach.

Comment: Do you have control of server?

Comment: @guest271314 no.